# How to undo changes in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there anyway to undo an update in postgreSQL?

I have used this query to update a column

```
UPDATE dashboard.inventory 
SET address = 'adf'
WHERE address @@ to_tsquery(('makati'))
```

but i made a huge stupid mistake because it was on a wrong column..

Comment: Tip of the day: ***Never use auto commit for adhoc updates***. Know what you want before the update. Run the query. Validate the results. Commit or Rollback as appropriate.  (Note Update here refers to all DML.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside a transaction block you can use : `ROLLBACK`

Answer (score 0):

If you have already committed or did it in autocommit mode, then no.

The data is perhaps still in your database, just not visible.  But autovacuum may soon clear it out, if it hasn't already.  To best preserve your options, immediately stop your database in immediate mode and do a complete file-level backup.  You could then hire a specialist firm to recovery it from that backup, if you decide to do that.

If you use WAL archiving, you could set up a copy of the database using point in time recovery, restored to just before the error, then use that to extract the lost column to a file, then use that repopulate the column in your real database.

Comment: Even if you don't have WAL archiving you can restore latest backup you have and read data from there. Of course everything done between your latest backup and your unfortunate query is gone. But quite often this is much better than losing all data in a column.